# State-sum construction of the Drinfeld center of a fusion 2-category

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory, fusion-categories, morita-equivalence

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a fusion 1-category, the Turaev-Viro state-sum produces a 3d TQFT whose modular tensor category is the Drinfeld center of $\mathcal{C}$. In particular this means that the Turaev-Viro construction for two Morita equivalent fusion categories gives the same 3d TQFT. Equivalently said, if $\mathcal{C}$ has Froboenius algebra objects $A$ we can contruct Morita equivalent categories by condensing $A$, which turns out the be the category of bimodules of $A$, and this corresponds to all possible Lagrangian algebra objects of the Drinfeld center.

My question is whether this extends to fusion 2-cateogries and 4d TQFTs. I know that there are state-sum constructions of 4d TQFTs from the datum of a braided fusion 1-category (which can be understood as a fusion 2-category with one simple object), like the Crane-Yetter state-sum, or more generally from the datum of a spherical fusion 2-category (by Douglas and Reutter). It seems that still the braided fusion 2-category associated to these 4d TQFT is the Drinfeld center of the fusion 2-category we started with (correct me if I am wrong), and this  is an invariant under Morita equivalences (for instance https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.04917). However in the case of fusion 1-cateogries the Drinfeld center is, in a certain sense, the unique invariant of the Morita equivalence classes, since for any Froboenius algebras of $\mathcal{C}$ there is a Lagrangian algebra object of $Z(\mathcal{C})$. It is not clear to me whether this is true also in the case of fusion 2-cateogries. Actually it seems to me that the Drinfeld center of a fusion 2-cateogory is not the only invariants of its Morita equivalence class.

One of the origins of my confusion is the following. The Crane-Yetter state sum for a modular tensor category produces a 4d TQFT which is an invertible theory, and can be thought as the anomaly inflow theory for the 3d Reshetikhin-Turaev theory of the starting MTC. However if the MTC has some commutative Froboenius algebra objects we could condense them producing Morita equivalent categories, and I would expect the Drinfeld center to have a corresponding Lagrangian algebra object. But this cannot be the case if the 4d TQFT is invertible... In other words all the MTCs have the same Drinfeld center (it is trivial) but not all of them are Morita equivalent. Is there something beyond the Drinfeld center which differentiate the various Morita equivalence classes?

Comment: The input of Turaev-Viro model is a spherical fusion 1-category $\mathcal{C}$, and it produces a **fully extended** 3d TQFT in the Morita 3-category of tensor categories c.f. [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7188) whose value on the circle $S^1$ gives you the Drinfeld center $\mathcal{Z}(\mathcal{C})$. In comparison, Reshetikhin-Turaev model takes a modular tensor category $\mathcal{M}$ as input, and produces a 3d TQFT **extended to 1d**, whose value on the circle $S^1$ gives you the original MTC $\mathcal{M}$. The former 3d TQFT thus can be viewed as **anomaly-free**, while the later 3d TQFT

Comment: (continued) is **anomalous**, whose **anomaly** can be described by a 4d TQFT, which is exactly the Crane-Yetter model you mentioned at the beginning. This 4d TQFT is (probably not surprising) **anomaly-free** again, which means you can extend it down to a point. Well, hypothetically this 4d TQFT should be realized as a symmetric monoidal 4-functor from the cobordism 4-category to the 4-category $\mathbf{4Vect}$. The target 4-category might have many inequivalant models, for example one could consider all linear 3-categories. Meanwhile, Cobordism Hypothesis tells us that nevertheless their

Comment: (continued) full subcategory of fully dualizable objects are always the same. Going back to the Crane-Yetter model, when your input is a MTC $\mathcal{M}$, the value assigned to the point by the corresponding 4d TQFT is the linear 3-category $\Sigma^2 \mathcal{M} := \mathbf{Mod}(\mathbf{Mod}(\mathcal{M}))$, or equivalently, the Morita class of monoidal 2-category $\mathbf{Mod}(\mathcal{M})$ of module categories over $\mathcal{M}$, with monoidal product given by the relative Deligne tensor product $\boxtimes_{\mathcal{M}}$. People say that Crane-Yetter model gives you an **invertible** 4d TQFT,

Comment: (continued) which means the value it assigned to the point, $\Sigma^2 \mathcal{M}$, is an invertible object under tensor product of linear 3-categories. In this paper of Brochier, Jordan, Safronov, Snyder [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.13812) the authors proved that this group of invertible linear 3-categories is the so-called **Witt group of non-degenerate braided fusion categories** defined by Davydov, Müger, Nikshych and Ostrik [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2117) If we ask for the value assigned by 4d Crane-Yetter TQFT to the circle $S^1$, then it is the trivial linear 2-category;

Comment: (continued) in other word, one has $\mathscr{Z}(\mathbf{Mod}(\mathcal{M})) = \mathbf{2Vect}$.

Comment: Now, regarding your questions on Morita equivalences, it seems to me you are probably asking two separate ones at the same time. The first question is, whether Drinfeld center of a fusion 2-category determines its Morita class. The answer to this question is yes-and-no. It is still fairly obvious that Drinfeld center 
$\mathscr{Z}(\mathfrak{C})$ is a Morita invariant for fusion 2-category $\mathfrak{C}$, as one can realize it as $\mathbf{End}_{\mathfrak{C} \boxtimes \mathfrak{C}^{1mp}}(\mathfrak{C})$. However, as we have observed from Crane-Yetter TQFT story, one could have fusion 2-category

Comment: (continued) $\mathbf{Mod}(\mathcal{M})$ not Morita equivalent to $\mathbf{2Vect}$, as long as MTC $\mathcal{M}$ has non-trivial Witt class. In the language of condensed matter physics, you may have two anomaly-free 3d topological orders with **no gapped domain wall** between them; in comparison, there **always exists** a gapped domain wall between two anomaly-free 2d topological orders.

Comment: The second question is about Morita equivalences between **algebras within a fusion 2-category** $\mathfrak{C}$ and Lagrangian algebras in the Drinfeld center $\mathscr{Z}(\mathfrak{C})$. In the setting of tensor 1-categories, their relationship is established by the construction of full center (Davydov et al.). Of course one could try to ask for a categorification in this setting of fusion 2-categories. The desired theory should tell you that full center of a separable algebra $A$ in the fusion 2-category $\mathfrak{C}$ is a Lagrangian algebra in Drinfeld center $\mathscr{Z}(\mathfrak{C})$;

Comment: (continued) moreover, full center is **Morita invariant** in the sense that if separable algebras $A$ and $B$ are Morita equivalent in $\mathfrak{C}$, then their full centers are equivalent **as braided algebras** in the Drinfeld center $\mathscr{Z}(\mathfrak{C})$. (I think) it is expected that the converse holds as well, i.e. separable algebras are Morita equivalent in $\mathfrak{C}$, then their full centers are equivalent in the Drinfeld center. If you take $\mathfrak{C} = \mathbf{2Vect}$, then this reproduces the classical statement (due to Etingof et al.) that

Comment: (continued) Morita equivalences between fusion categories are in one-to-one correspondence with braided equivalences between their Drinfeld centers.

Answer (score 0):

(Summary of the comments:)
The input of Turaev-Viro model is a spherical fusion 1-category $\mathcal{C}$, and it produces a **fully extended** 3d TQFT in the Morita 3-category of tensor categories c.f. [DSPS](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7188) whose value on the circle $S^1$ gives you the Drinfeld center $\mathcal{Z}(\mathcal{C})$. In comparison, Reshetikhin-Turaev model takes a modular tensor category $\mathcal{M}$ as input, and produces a 3d TQFT **extended down to 1d**, whose value on the circle $S^1$ gives you the original MTC $\mathcal{M}$.

The former 3d TQFT can be viewed as **anomaly-free**, while the later 3d TQFT is **anomalous**, whose **anomaly** can be described by a 4d TQFT, which is exactly the Crane-Yetter model you mentioned at the beginning. This 4d TQFT is (probably not surprising) *anomaly-free* again, which means you can extend it down to a point. Hypothetically this 4d TQFT should be realized as a symmetric monoidal 4-functor from the cobordism 4-category to the 4-category $\mathbf{4Vect}$.

The target 4-category might have many inequivalant models, for example one could consider all linear 3-categories. Meanwhile, Cobordism Hypothesis tells us that nevertheless their full subcategory of **fully dualizable** objects are always the same.

Going back to the Crane-Yetter model, when your input is a MTC $\mathcal{M}$, the value assigned to the point by the corresponding 4d TQFT is the linear 3-category $\Sigma^2 \mathcal{M} := \mathbf{Mod}(\mathbf{Mod}(\mathcal{M}))$, or equivalently, the Morita class of monoidal 2-category $\mathbf{Mod}(\mathcal{M})$ of module categories over $\mathcal{M}$, with monoidal product given by the relative Deligne tensor product $\boxtimes_{\mathcal{M}}$.

When people say that Crane-Yetter model gives you an *invertible* 4d TQFT, they mean the value it assigned to the point, $\Sigma^2 \mathcal{M}$, is an invertible object under tensor product of linear 3-categories. In this paper of Brochier, Jordan, Safronov, Snyder [BJSS](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.13812), the authors proved that this group of invertible linear 3-categories is the so-called **Witt group of non-degenerate braided fusion categories** defined by Davydov, Müger, Nikshych and Ostrik [DMNO](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2117). If we ask for the value assigned by 4d Crane-Yetter TQFT to the circle $S^1$, then it is the trivial linear 2-category $\mathbf{2Vect}$; mathematically, one has $\mathscr{Z}(\mathbf{Mod}(\mathcal{M})) = \mathbf{2Vect}$ as braided fusion 2-categories.

---

**Question 1. Does Drinfeld center of a fusion 2-category determine its Morita class?**

The answer to this question is *yes-and-no*. It is still fairly obvious that Drinfeld center $\mathscr{Z}(\mathfrak{C})$ is a Morita invariant for fusion 2-category $\mathfrak{C}$, as one can realize it as $\mathbf{End}_{\mathfrak{C} \boxtimes \mathfrak{C}^{1mp}}(\mathfrak{C})$. However, as we have observed from Crane-Yetter TQFT story, one could have fusion 2-category $\mathbf{Mod}(\mathcal{M})$ not Morita equivalent to $\mathbf{2Vect}$, as long as MTC $\mathcal{M}$ has non-trivial Witt class. In the language of condensed matter physics, you may have two anomaly-free 3d topological orders with no gapped domain wall between them; in comparison, there always exists a gapped domain wall between two anomaly-free 2d topological orders.

---

**Question 2. What is the relationship between algebras in a fusion 2-category $\mathfrak{C}$ and Lagrangian algebras in the Drinfeld center $\mathscr{Z}(\mathfrak{C})$?**

In the setting of tensor 1-categories, their relationship is established by the construction of **full center** (Davydov et al.). Of course one could try to ask for a categorification in this setting of fusion 2-categories. The desired theory of full center should tell you that

- Full center of a (connected) separable algebra $A$ in the fusion 2-category $\mathfrak{C}$ is a Lagrangian algebra in Drinfeld center $\mathscr{Z}(\mathfrak{C})$;
- Full center is Morita invariant in the sense that if connected separable algebras $A$ and $B$ are Morita equivalent in $\mathfrak{C}$, then their full centers are equivalent as *braided algebras* in the Drinfeld center $\mathscr{Z}(\mathfrak{C})$.
- (**Conjectured**) Furthermore, if two connected separable algebras have equivalent full centers in the Drinfeld center, then they are Morita equivalent.

If you take $\mathfrak{C} = \mathbf{2Vect}$, then this reproduces the classical statement (due to Etingof et al.) that Morita equivalences between fusion categories are in one-to-one correspondence with braided equivalences between their Drinfeld centers. On the other hand, take $\mathfrak{C} = \mathbf{2Vect}_G$ for some finite group $G$, then this claims the correspondence between Morita equivalences between $G$-graded fusion categories and their full centers in $\mathscr{Z}(\mathbf{2Vect}_G)$, which are $G$-crossed braided fusion categories.

---

Finally, maybe it is beneficial to remark on the classification of fusion 2-categories in general. Firstly, [Décoppet](https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.16827) has proven that any fusion 2-category is Morita equivalent to a strongly fusion 2-category, i.e. a fusion 2-category equivalent to either of the two cases:

- [**bosonic**] $\mathbf{2Vect}_G^\pi$, where the twist of pentagonator is given by a group 4-cocycle $\pi$ on finite group $G$.
- [**fermionic**] $\mathbf{2sVect}_G^\varpi$, where the twist of pentagonator is given by a group super 4-cocycle $\varpi \in \mathrm{SH}^4(G) := [BG,B\mathbf{BrPic}(\mathbf{2sVect})]$.

Thence, for any fusion 2-category $\mathfrak{C}$, we can always find a braided equivalence $\mathscr{Z}(\mathfrak{C}) \simeq \mathscr{Z}(\mathbf{2Vect}_G^\pi)$ (in the bosonic case) or $\mathscr{Z}(\mathfrak{C}) \simeq \mathscr{Z}(\mathbf{2sVect}_G^\varpi)$ (in the fermionic case). Using results from [DX](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.02843), this corresponds to find a Lagrangian algebra $L$ in $\mathscr{Z}(\mathbf{2Vect}_G^\pi)$ or $\mathscr{Z}(\mathbf{2sVect}_G^\varpi)$. Thus the classification of fusion 2-categories reduced to

- [bosonic fusion 2-categories] classification of non-degenerate $G$-crossed braided multifusion categories compatible with twist $\pi$,
- [fermionic fusion 2-categories] classification of non-degenerate $G$-crossed braided multifusion super-categories compatible with twist $\varpi$.